# Joining multiple models in order to get an orm query in Django?

Tags: python, django, django-queryset, django-orm

I have to return the average length of the most sold tracks in a certain time, using 3 models i manage to form an sql query that looks something like this

```
select  AVG(t.Milliseconds) as lengthTrack
from invoice_items as il
    join invoices as i on i.invoiceid = il.invoiceid
    join tracks as t on t.TrackId = il.TrackId 
where i.InvoiceDate between '2012-01-01' and '2013-12-31'
order by il.Quantity DESC LIMIT 10
```

I manage to come up with this as I got really confused about how to join both tables in order to get the average length track of the 10 most sold ones :

```
start_date = datetime.date(2012, 01, 01)
end_date=datetime.date(2013, 12, 31)

InvoiceItem .objects.filter(ino_date__range=(start_date, end_date),)
```

model.py

```
class Invoice(models.Model):
    id                = models.AutoField(primary_key=True, db_column='InvoiceId')
    customerid        = models.ForeignKey(Customer, db_column='CustomerId', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    invoicedate       = models.DateTimeField(db_column='InvoiceDate')
    billingaddress    = models.TextField(max_length=70, db_column='BillingAddress', blank=True, null=True)
    billingcity       = models.TextField(max_length=40, db_column='BillingCity', blank=True, null=True)
    billingstate      = models.TextField(max_length=40, db_column='BillingState', blank=True, null=True)
    billingcountry    = models.TextField(max_length=40, db_column='BillingCountry', blank=True, null=True)
    billingpostalcode = models.TextField(max_length=10, db_column='BillingPostalCode', blank=True, null=True)
    total             = models.TextField(db_column='Total')

class Track(models.Model):
    id           = models.AutoField(primary_key=True, db_column='TrackId')
    playlist     = models.ManyToManyField(Playlist, through='PlaylistTrack')
    name         = models.TextField(db_column='Name', max_length=200)
    albumid      = models.ForeignKey(Album, db_column='AlbumId', blank=True, null=True, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    mediatypeid  = models.ForeignKey(MediaType, db_column='MediaTypeId', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    genreid      = models.ForeignKey(Genre, db_column='GenreId', blank=True, null=True, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    composer     = models.TextField(db_column='Composer', blank=True, null=True, max_length=220)
    milliseconds = models.IntegerField(db_column='Milliseconds')
    bytes        = models.IntegerField(db_column='Bytes', blank=True, null=True)
    unitprice    = models.DecimalField(db_column='UnitPrice', max_digits=5, decimal_places=2)

class InvoiceItem(models.Model):
    id        = models.AutoField(primary_key=True, db_column='InvoiceLineId')
    invoiceid = models.ForeignKey(Invoice, db_column='InvoiceId', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    trackid   = models.ForeignKey(Track, db_column='TrackId', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    unitprice = models.DecimalField(db_column='UnitPrice', max_digits=5, decimal_places=2)
    quantity  = models.IntegerField(db_column='Quantity')
```

serialerzs.py

```
class InvoiceSerialer(serializers.HyperlinkedModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Invoice
        fields = ('id', 'total')


class InvoiceItemSerialer(serializers.HyperlinkedModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = InvoiceItem
        fields = '__all__'


class TrackSerialer(serializers.HyperlinkedModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Track
        fields = '__all__'
```

in the views do i need to add the 3 serializers in erializer_class? i also wanna ask if my query right ?

Comment: More code needed to answer this.  In your SQL query you reference table `m` that isn't in the query.  It's tough to help you build the Django query without the underlying models.  Also, your question doesn't address views or serializers, so that's a red herring.  The query should be writable with just models and managers.  So you can test it in the Django shell without needing a view or serializers.  Post your model code and we can help you generate the query.

Comment: i've edited my question and i added the model and serialerzs files

Answer (score 1):

Getting the most sold between dates is going to be a matter of annotating the tracks with how many times they were sold between those dates.

```
from django.db.models import Count, Q
top_ten_selling_tracks = Track.objects.annotate(
   sales_count=Count( 
      'invoice_item', # count the number of invoices that point to this track
      filter=Q(invoiceid__invoicedate__range=(start_date, end_date)) # only count them if the associated invoice falls in the appropriate range
   )).order_by(
      '-sales_count' # order them by sales descending, to get the top 10
   )[:10] # take the top ten tracks
```

The average can be done in python (Django can aggregate over a queryset easily, but with your limit constraint it's probably easier to just

```
return avg(t.milliseconds for t in top_ten_selling_tracks)
```

Comment: do i need to add the 3 models in the serializer_class in order for this query to work ? if so how to add 3 models at the same time because when i look up the docs it says its not possible ?

Comment: Your question was how to get the query.  This query will work regardless of serializer.  Perhaps you are trying to return this in a DRF serializer for a REST API?  But it's not clear which serializer would contain this information - none of your serializers return aggregation over multiple objects - it's not a property of a track, an invoice, or an invoiceitem to have the "average length of the top 10 selling tracks".  You probably want to write just a simple API View function to return this value, but it's difficult to say without knowing your use case.

Comment: i need to return average length of the top 10 most sold tracks between 2012 and 2013 from those tables but when i tried your function i had a problem in the return its says it messing an ")" i don't know where the annotate func should be closed ?

Comment: I fixed the parens - I missed the one at the end of the filter.  Sorry for that! And as for "I need to return average length..." - I get that, but return it where and to whom?  If you were putting it on a serializer you would be returning it as a property of a serialized object.  What object?  If it's just an API endpoint that's needed to return that value, write a short API view https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/views/#api_view

Comment: its for a rest api that i'll need to consume later in the front

Comment: Yeah in that case just an api view that returns the result of this query makes more sense than a serializer

Comment: didn't work with the api view i don't know why

Comment: sounds like a new question.  If you test this query in the Django shell (`python manage.py shell`, then import your models and run the query from the repl) does it work?  If so open a new question for the api view issue you're having.

Comment: its asking me for a basename which i added inoviceitem and now its says that i need to provied the queryset or or override the `get_queryset()` method

Comment: yeah - that's because you're making a modelserializer, not an api view.  I'm saying an api view, like a regular django view function, that runs this query.  Like `def top_track_avg_time(request): return <your query>`

Comment: well in this case can i make it work with sterilize method? cuz when i tried that it says Could not resolve URL for hyperlinked relationship using view name "track-detail"

Comment: a ModelSerializer is meant to return a serialized instance of one model.  The query you're talking about returns data about ALL models.  So it doesn't make sense to be a method on a serializer.  You could write a generic serializers.Serializer that serializes a simple object that contains this query, but that's a lot of work to just return a value in JSON as a REST API.  The right way would be to write an API endpoint that returns this value.